Why was Panama Railroad in poor condition when US decided to build Panama Canal in 1904?
I had thought the Panama Canal was the cause of Panama Railroad's decline. But I found out that in 1904 when US government decided to build the Panama Canal, Panama Railroad was already in bad shape. Why was that?
I ask because, to quote from wiki and some other materials, e.g. David McCullough's "Brave Companions",

The railroad became one of the most profitable in the world. Upon
completion, the railway was proclaimed an engineering marvel of the
era. Until the opening of the Panama Canal, it carried the heaviest
volume of freight per unit length of any railroad in the world.

What had happened to make Panama Railroad decline?
Besides, why did the French Company purchase a controlling interest in the Panama Railway in 1881? Wasn't Panama Railway the US people's great achievement?

I have a book at home, The Path Between the Seas (also from McCullough), that talks about that railroad extensively. I'll try to consult it when I get home to polish this answer up, but my memory of things is:
You have to understand that this was not a normal railroad that you may be used to thinking about, running through inhabited and tamed areas. It had to traverse both mountains and rainforests (often at the same time). It was also run though a highly geologically active area. This means new track disruptions due to natural phenomenon were constant. Mudslides, rockslides, avalanches, earthquakes, floods, flora, fauna all could and would completely shut down the line regularly. Any bridges or trestles made of wood (which is what they liked to use initially because the wood was plentiful in the area, so it made construction much quicker) would rot quickly.
Also, the area it ran through ranged from barely habitable right on the coast, to completely uninhabitable in the interor. Since nobody lived in the interior, any repairmen, and all of their supplies and materials, had to be brought in on the remaining good rail from one of the coasts. In the cases of major disruptions like earthquakes or mudslides, the amount of labor and equipment needed to fix the issue might be extensive.
To top it off, the area was a paradise for mosquitos. The labor-hungry French canal engineering efforts in the area brought in workers from all over the world, which also brought in the world's tropical diseases. Yellow Fever in particular became not just endemic, but prevalent. This is probably what really killed the French canal projects, because they just couldn't keep canal workers alive*. Railway maintenance workers would have been in the same boat.
What finally made work in the canal zone feasible was that when the US took over, they sent over a medical professional who actually believed in the relatively new germ theory, knew how to fight mosquitoes, and had the authority to order the doubters to take the measures he wanted against their will if need be.
Anyway, if you're interested in this, I'd highly suggest picking up and/or borrowing a copy of McCullough's The Path Between the Seas.

* - I remember reading this and thinking how morally reprehensible it was to even keep trying. It had devolved into the civil engineering equivalent of a human wave attack.

As for the second question, I think they likely needed to leverage the government right-of-ways given to the railway to build the canal, but that's just a SWAG. The book probably will say, if I can find where I hid it.

Thanks for the answer but after finding out the book "The Path Between the Seas" has 700 pages I think I will pass, especially English is not my native language. :(

@Qiulang邱朗 - Yeah, it was a looong read. Mainly because it covered several eras. He really could have split it into 3 books (The Railway, The Failed French effort, and the Successful American one), except of course that the earlier stories are quite helpful context for reading the later ones.

I was amused to see you added the word, "human wave attack". I had thought this was a Chinese term. Besides, Human (人) wave (海) attack （战术）seems to be a word-for-word translation from its Chinese counterpart. In Chinese this expression has evolved to be more than military sense . Is this the case in English ?

@Qiulang邱朗 Definitely also an English term—often an intensely loaded one, at that. At least in English, usually used to describe the allegedly-shoddy tactics of one’s enemies as a way to boost morale (they are poorly trained/ill equipped), motivate fighting (look how evil they are, treating their own people like that), and excuse leadership on your own side (we’re still better than that). I can’t find a good treatment of the term’s history in English, but it may be notable that the first example in the English Wikipedia page is from the Boxer Rebellion, which may suggest a Chinese origin.

Well I will argue that in The Art of War,  Sun Tzu said  " It is the rule in war, if our forces are ten to the enemy’s one, to surround him; if five to one, to attack him .. ". The was probably the origin of the Chinese term.  https://my.tlu.edu/ICS/icsfs/SunTzu21pg.pdf?target=06dde2fe-20a6-4589-8c78-ea0854b093f3

@Qiulang邱朗 - Try following the handy link I provided for the term - there's a whole Wikipedia page about it. KRyan is correct that its usually meant as an insult to the attackers or their leadership. Otherwise it would be termed something like a "frontal assault"

@T.E.D. I had read the link when you added it and as I said I felt assumed because I didn't know English also had such expression. In modern Chinese context, it is more about low efficient, waste of resource.

It lost its appeal after 1867, and, after bankruptcy of the French, deteriorated quickly.
Remember that is a railroad built across the jungle (just its construction took 5,000 to 10,000 deaths for 76 km).
Here is the timeline, until 1893 - when deterioration happened:
1855: Completion of the first railroad implementation, and it started to make money.
1867 onwards (page 5): business started declining:

renegotiation of license with Colombia: the company had to pay $1,000,000 upfront and then $250,000 annually,
the Pacific Steam Navigation Company, monopolist of South American trade, reroutes its ships to force rate adjustment, and
completion of first transcontinental rail across the USA.

And so the company was no longer making as much money.
1880: foundation of Universal Company of the Interoceanic Canal of Panama (source in French, but Google Translate makes it readable) created to build the Panama Canal, for a cost of 600 million francs (underestimated to not frighten investors).
1883: French took ownership of the railway. (page 6)
1893: Panama scandals - the French went bankrupt, and the railway deteriorated rapidly. No money to do maintenance, of a railway in a harsh environment that was not making as much money as the beginning

Very good answer. IMHO a lot of the answer I wrote just explains why "the railway deteriorated rapidly" was quite feasible when money got tight.

Little to no profit to be made by whatever owner, what would have been the point in maintaining it?

So the french company bought the railway in order to buy the canal ?

@Qiulang邱朗 bought the railway in order to make the canal… they needed the railway to move men’s an materials
